# makefile does not use the compiler flags

Tags: makefile

I have this makefile:

```
CC=g++
DEPS = object.hpp utils.hpp
OBJ = object.o main.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -Wall -lglut -lGL

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -Wall -lglut -lGL
```

Then, when I make `make`, this happens:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o object.o object.cpp
```

When I wanted:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o object.o object.cpp -Wall -lglut -lGL
```

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your rule specifies how to build a `.o` from a `.c`.  But your files are named `.cpp`, not `.c`.  Rewrite:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -Wall -lglut -lGL
```

However, adding linker flags like `-l` to your compile lines will lead to errors.